pytest how to implementation a plugin to execute by every directory
My project struct like
.
├── test_dir_1
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_case_1.py
│   └── test_case_3.py
└── test_dir_2
├── conftest.py
└── test_case_2.py

conftest:
import pytest
from loguru import logger

@pytest.fixture(scope="package", autouse=True)
def package_hook(request):
    logger.info("suite setup hook")
    yield
    logger.info("suite teardown hook")

This structure execution log like

... INFO     | test_dir_1.conftest:package_hook:7 - suite setup hook
PASSED
... INFO     | test_dir_1.conftest:package_hook:10 - suite teardown hook


... INFO     | test_dir_2.conftest:package_hook:7 - suite setup hook
PASSED
... INFO     | test_dir_2.conftest:package_hook:10 - suite teardown hook

Now I hope to omit the conftest files in the directory and still retain functionality;
I am trying to create a conftest file in the root path of the project, like this:

.
├── conftest.py
├── test_dir_1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_case_1.py
│   └── test_case_3.py
└── test_dir_2
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_case_2.py

conftest:
import pytest
from loguru import logger


@pytest.fixture(scope="package", autouse=True)
def package_hook(request):
    logger.info("suite setup hook")

    yield
    logger.info("suite teardown hook")

But the execution results and expectations are not satisfactory，
This structure execution log like

... | INFO     | conftest:package_hook:7 - suite setup hook
PASSED
PASSED
... | INFO     | conftest:package_hook:10 - suite teardown hook

I hope to execute each directory once instead of only executing once in total.
How should I implement it, perhaps by using other hooks to dynamically add conftest to the test directory?
